# How to set custom order total in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I currently have 6 items in cart, which cost `£456`.  I'm trying to implement a custom payment system, so the customer can pay some now and some later.  So i want the cost to be `£400`.

The only function i've found is `set_total` in `WC_Abstract_Order` but to use WC_Abstract Order you need the order id and the order hasn't been placed yet for an id to be generated.

Any idea how to solve?